# ORA-00927: missing equal sign java eclipse

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, oracle, sql-update

When I try to run a code I got an error message "ORA-00927: missing equal sign" which can not detect it in the code and can not fix it. I mean that error is in the `UPDATE` method but i'm not sure.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;strong text
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import net.proteanit.*;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

public class Korisnici extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Korisnici frame = new Korisnici();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Connection connection = null;
    protected ResultSet rs;
    private JTextField textFieldPhoneNumber;
    private JTextField textFieldName;
    private JTextField textFieldEmail;
    private JTextField textFieldID;


    public Korisnici() {
        connection = sqlConnection.dbConnector();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 777, 512);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnLoadTable = new JButton("Load \"Korisnici\" table");
        btnLoadTable.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        btnLoadTable.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                try {
                    String query = "SELECT * FROM KORISNICI";
            PreparedStatement pst= connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet ps = pst.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(ps));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        btnLoadTable.setBounds(411, 11, 211, 50);
        contentPane.add(btnLoadTable);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(305, 83, 446, 311);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        JLabel lblId = new JLabel("ID");
        lblId.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblId.setBounds(10, 83, 115, 60);
        contentPane.add(lblId);

        JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("Email");
        lblEmail.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblEmail.setBounds(10, 154, 115, 60);
        contentPane.add(lblEmail);

        JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name");
        lblName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblName.setBounds(10, 225, 115, 60);
        contentPane.add(lblName);

        JLabel lblPhonenumber = new JLabel("Phone number");
        lblPhonenumber.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblPhonenumber.setBounds(10, 296, 120, 60);
        contentPane.add(lblPhonenumber);

        textFieldPhoneNumber = new JTextField();
        textFieldPhoneNumber.setBounds(135, 313, 155, 30);
        contentPane.add(textFieldPhoneNumber);
        textFieldPhoneNumber.setColumns(10);

        textFieldName = new JTextField();
        textFieldName.setBounds(135, 242, 155, 30);
        contentPane.add(textFieldName);
        textFieldName.setColumns(10);

        textFieldEmail = new JTextField();
        textFieldEmail.setBounds(135, 171, 155, 30);
        contentPane.add(textFieldEmail);
        textFieldEmail.setColumns(10);

        textFieldID = new JTextField();
        textFieldID.setBounds(135, 100, 155, 30);
        contentPane.add(textFieldID);
        textFieldID.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    String query = "INSERT INTO korisnici (ID, EMAIL, NAME, PHONE_NUMBER) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    pst.setString(1, textFieldID.getText());
                    pst.setString(2, textFieldEmail.getText());
                    pst.setString(3, textFieldName.getText());
                    pst.setString(4, textFieldPhoneNumber.getText());

                    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved");

                    pst.close();
                    rs.close();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnSave.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        btnSave.setBounds(10, 400, 90, 40);
        contentPane.add(btnSave);

        JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");
        btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    String query = "UPDATE korisnici SET ID='"+textFieldID.getText()+"' ,email='"+textFieldEmail.getText()+"' ,name='"+textFieldName.getText()+"' ,Phone number='"+textFieldPhoneNumber.getText()+"'  ";
                    PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);


                    pst.execute();

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Updated");

                    pst.close();

                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnUpdate.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        btnUpdate.setBounds(110, 400, 90, 40);
        contentPane.add(btnUpdate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant portion of your code, especially when you managed to narrow the error down to a single line

Comment: i think update is the issue, as there is no `where` clause associated with it

Comment: If you are using prepared statements, then do the smart thing and use parameters with them.

Comment: I bet that the error is the missing underscore for phone_number in the UPDATE statement. But in any case, please use parameters just like you did with the INSERT statement!

Answer (score 3):

The update:

```
String query = "UPDATE korisnici SET ID='"+textFieldID.getText()
       +"' ,email='"+textFieldEmail.getText()+"',name='"+textFieldName.getText()
      +"' ,Phone number='"+textFieldPhoneNumber.getText()+"'  ";
```

constains this snippet:

```
 .... ,Phone number='"+ .....
```

In Oracle nonquoted identifiers cannot contain spaces, see this:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm

> 6. Nonquoted identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters from
>      your database character set and the underscore (_), dollar sign ($),
>      and pound sign (#). Database links can also contain periods (.) and
>      "at" signs (@). Oracle strongly discourages you from using $ and # in
>      nonquoted identifiers.
>
> Quoted identifiers can contain any characters and punctuations marks
>   as well as spaces. However, neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers
>   can contain double quotation marks or the null character (\0).

In other words: `Phone number` is treated as a column named `Phone`, and Oracle expects `=` after a column name in the update statement, but it gets `number`, then throws the error.